# Why am I getting an ESLint error for async function with Promise return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a Next.js application where I am defining an async function with Promise return and using it as an event handler for a HTML anchor element. However, when I try to run my code, ESLint is throwing the following error:

> "Promise-returning function provided to variable where a void return was expected.(@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises)"

Here's my code:

`const { data: users, mutate: mutateUsers } = useSWR( { url: endpoints.users(), args: { id: userId || "" } }, ({ args }) => getUsers(args.userId || ""));`

```
const { data: myData, mutate: mutateData }   = useSWR(
    { url: endpoints.data(), args: { id: id || "" } },
    ({ args }) => getData(args.id || ""));`
```

The ESLint error is being triggered by the use of the async keyword in the updateData function that is defined as a MouseEventHandler.

```
 const updateData: MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement> = 
      async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          await mutateUsers();        
          await mutateData();    
       };
```

And here's the **HTML** code that calls the updateData function:

`<a className="alert-link" href="#" onClick={ updateData }>`         
Update

`

I am not sure why ESLint is throwing this error and how to fix it. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance for any help.

I have tried this solution:

```
const updateData: MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement> = (e) => {
   (async => { e.preventDefault();
   await mutateUsers();
   await mutateData();
 })
};
```

`<a className="alert-link" href="#" onClick={ updateData }>        Update        <myButton name=""/>    </a>`

but It doesn't work

Comment: Hello friend! Your post has significant formatting issues that makes it very hard to understand. Please [edit] your question and put code between three backticks like ``` to separate it from the rest of post. I tried to clean it up for you but I think I only made it worse. Spend some time formatting it nicely and we will spend some trying to answer it.

Comment: @AlexWayne Why roll back your edit? It looked good [that way](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75632670/2), it was definitely an improvement

Comment: Define the async func inside the event listener and call it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an `async` function (or any `Promise`-returning) function as a callback to a function that ignores the return value of the callback (i.e. expecting a callback that returns `void`) is a problem, because that means the function will invoke the callback and not *handle* the promise. In particular, it will ignore if the returned promise rejects, which will lead to a global unhandled promise rejection error which could crash a nodejs app.

Admittedly, this is not a problem just for promise-returning functions, it's the same problem when you pass a callback that throws a synchronous exception. Would the function know to handle the error?<sup>1</sup> Where would the exception propagate to? (It's actually fine if the callback was called immediately, it could just bubble back up to the caller).

However, this is generally not a problem for event handlers in the browser. For one, it doesn't crash a web application. But mainly, it's because event handlers are *expected* not to have their errors handled, whether they be synchronous or asynchronous<sup>2</sup>. If the programmer cared<sup>3</sup>, they would have handled the error inside the `async` function implementation, and would return a promise that would never reject.
So you can basically safely ignore the linter here. Just suppress the error. As an alternative, you can use the `void` operator to explicitly ignore the promise:

```
const updateData: MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement> = (e) => {
  void (async => {
//^^^^
    e.preventDefault();
    await mutateUsers();
    await mutateData();
  })();
//  ^^ don't forget to call the IIAFE
};
<button onClick={ updateData }>
```

or

```
const updateData = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await mutateUsers();
  await mutateData();
};
<button onClick={ e => void updateData(e) }>
```

<sub>1: And we don't know. We (and the linter) cannot really know, since the TypeScript type system fails to model exceptions. The main difference to when a promise is ignored that we *do* know, and that's why this rule can exist.

2: Actually, asynchronous functions are expected to be more error-prone since they usually do IO which may fail, while synchronous event handlers rarely throw.

3: And they should. *You* should.</sub>